# Localized ipad .nib file doesnt work

Tags: ios, ipad, localization, xib, nib

I have an iPhone application which i am trying to convert to universal.

I have a viewController that has 2 localized .xib (English and Spanish) files , that work great.

Now in order to target the iPad too , i created a viewController~ipad.xib file which is loaded correctly whenever i run the app in my iPad.

The problem occured when i tried to localize the .xib file and created an English and Spanish version exactly as i did for he iPhone.

Now whenever i run the app in the iPad , instead of getting the ipad .xib i get the iphone on screen!

Any ideas?

*I am not programmatically choosing which .xib file to run (for iphone and ipad) , i just have my files like:

```
controller.xib

controller~ipad.xib
```

Comment: Are you putting the `.xib` files into the language-specific resource folder?  I thought the `~ipad` and `~iphone` only affected launch images and not NIB files?

Comment: No they are affecting .nib files too. What do you mean language specific resource folder? I just clicked on my .xib file , then on the file inspector and then from the localization button i created another .xib . both .xib files named ¨controller~ipad.xib (English)¨ and ¨controller~ipad.xib (Spanish)¨ are under the ¨controller~ipad.xib¨ . What folder are you talking about?

Comment: The `en.lproj`, `es.lproj`, etc. folders.

Comment: ah yes , i am sorry i didnt understand what u meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently xCode needed a restart..

I tried multiple times to clean the project but that didn't help.

After restart everything works ok.

Comment: Hello @d0nparalias, you should accept your own answer if it worked :)

Comment: You can accept your own answer minimum 2 days after you posted the question. I will :)

Comment: This is messed up - Xcode IDE shouldn't really store state that affects the build process, but apparently it must do!

Comment: Did u have the same problem and the restart helped?

Comment: Seems bug here. Same happen to me. Only after restart xCode all worked properly.